# Build Link via AMPScript and track?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

has anyone an idea to create a link automatically and track this link in exact target?

I already find a suggestion with `TreatAsContentArea()`, `TreatAsContent()` and `ReturnTo()` both all didn't work for me.

With `TreatAsContentArea()` i cannot open the link without an error.

With `TreatAsContent()` the link works like a charm, but the link still didn't tracked.

And last but not least `ReturnTo()` also not work, because the link inside would also be an AMPscript function. So again, i receive an error.

So would it be possible to create a link with customers parameters like SubscriberID, MemberID etc?

As I notice, MC translate the link into a string of numbers .. is there any way to generate them too?

Answer (score 2):

You would use the RedirectTo function.

http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/http_ampscript_functions/redirectto/